# preg_replace doesn't work

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've small preg_replace problem. I need to resize iframe code output so I'm using preg_replace, regex seems to work fine, but result is same as input no changes. Here code I'm using:

```
$video_code = preg_replace( '/width="(.*?)"/', 'width="'.$width.'"',  $video_code );
$video_code = preg_replace( '/height="(.*?)"/', 'height="'.$height.'"',  $video_code );
```

This iframe that `$video_code` contains:

```
<iframe class='sproutvideo-player' type='text/html' src='http://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/189bd8b4191ee1c390/d0dc5859e1d409ed?type=hd&regularColors0=666565&regularColors1=595756&hoverColors0=ed2409&hoverColors1=d1390f&highlightColors1=c9c3c9&noBigPlay=true' width='768' height='432' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks

George

Comment: What is `$video_code` **exactly**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$video_code = preg_replace ('/(width=[\'"])(.*?)([\'"])/', '$1620$3',  $video_code);

$video_code = preg_replace ('/(height=[\'"])(.*?)([\'"])/', '$1' . $height . '$3',  $video_code);
```

Escaped some characters and you're replacing everything inbetween the `()`, so the text `height=` in the replacement pattern is unnecessary.

Comment: Your code replace whole widht and height parameters with numbers, didn't worked with iframe though. Sorry I pasted wrong code, here's update and iframe code itself.

Comment: You're using different quote (`'` instead of `"`) - updated my code

Comment: So quotes were causing all problems, your code still replaces whole width and height declaration with numbers, placed old `'width="'.$width.'"'` and it works fine. Is there any way to replace only values of width and height with appropriate new values?

Comment: Thanks works fine with editions I mentioned above, can you explain in more details what `$1` and `$3` do?

Comment: Simple, every `(...)` block captures it's content into `$n` variables, so the first block is in `$1` and so on. In this case, the first and third blocks are what's around the width/height values, so it should be pasted in the beginning and at the end. The second block is the actual value you want to replace.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? This regex simply puts the quotes, whether single or double, in the first and third block, so they both work

Comment: I mean variables wrapped in single quotes as in your example - `$1`.

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't that work, they would simply be captured by the first block and put in front in the replacement?

Comment: PHP doesn't process variables inside single quotes so this - `'$1620$3'` will be outputted as $1620$3. Thanks a lot for Regex fix.

Comment: No, normally it doesn't, but it does within the replacement parameter of preg_replace: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php (look at the examples)

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and it worked fine for me. (made a few small changes, but not much)

Here is the code i used:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/fafGYW

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$video_code = preg_replace('/width=[\'"][^\'"]+[\'"]/', 'width="'.$width.'"', $video_code);
$video_code = preg_replace('/height=[\'"][^\'"]+[\'"]/', 'height="'.$height.'"', $video_code);
```